# JS Manga Reader with WordPress NoConflict JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i am in a little bit of a pinch because i am not a js guy so i need some help here.

I have an HTML/JS page of a manga reader for a website, now the problem is that using regular JQuery the page works fine:

https://codepen.io/angcastillo59/pen/OxrgQd

But since WordPress JQuery runs in noConflict mode i have this:

https://codepen.io/angcastillo59/pen/GMPEzz

I've read that using this it should work but i am either using it wrong or definitely using it wrong:

```
(function($) { js stuff })( jQuery );
```

How do i make my js stuff work with WordPress JQuery?

Comment: you could just write jQuery instead of $. Example: jQuery(myElement).on('click', ...);

Comment: You're right, this is the answer, used it on my controls and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is how they format any javascript or jQuery for enqueuing in WordPress from the Boilerplate generator template. Works every time for me with no issue.

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    $(function() {
        /* Insert script here */
    });

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Already tried it in the pen, does not work, also the code i am using only makes the select box work, everything else doesn't.

Comment: You can't really test this code in the CodePen as it will not mimic what WordPress is doing.  Test it on a local or server install of WordPress.  Other things to keep in mind is that the script requires jQuery so when you enqueue it with wp_enqueue_script() it requires the jQuery library to be included in it's dependencies.

Comment: Post all your code where you enqueue the script and I'll see where the issue is.

Comment: Figured it out, my code both in the pen and wordpress was right, but the controls where using the onclick="return nextPage();", so i replaced it with $('.next').on('click', function() { /* nextPage function content */ }, also i checked and my pen does mimic what wordpress does because in it i am loading a JQuery no conflict the same way wordpress does, so when i figured out the problem it worked perfectly both in the pen and wordpress.